Inconvenience of speed of light in optic fiber
As far as I'm concerned, optic fiber is great in order to transport information quickly using light. Since light needs to undergo total internal reflection every single time it hits the walls of the optic fiber in order to not lose information, I understand the optic fiber's refractive index must be considerably high, as in order to minimize the critical angle, one must achieve: $\theta_C=\arcsin(n_{air}/n_{fiber})\to 0$. Nonetheless, taking into account optic fiber is usually a dielectric, the more we reduce the critical angle (the bigger we make $n_{fiber}$), the more slowly information will travel, since the speed of light will decrease as $v=\frac{c}{n_{fiber}}$. Therefore, my question is: can we optimize the value of $n'$ in order to lose as little information as possible while ensuring the speed of light in the fiber is high enough?
I'm guessing the speed of light is always high enough, since even if we reduce the critical angle to $\theta_C=0.57$º ($n_{fiber}=100$), information would still be travelling at millions of meters per second.

It is not clear which problem you want to solve. Are you thinking of very thick multi-mode fibers?

What speed of light do you require?

@JosBergervoet I'm afraid I'm not that versed into optic fibers, I just have in mind the oversimplified model of dielectric cylinder through which light travels without escaping it due to total internal reflection. The problem I'm addressing is, if we want to ensure none of the light escapes, then the refractive index of the fiber should be very high, but this would make the signal go slower

@Anyon is there a standard?

@Lagrangiano The rule of thumb I've always seen for fibers used in communication is that the index of refraction is about 1.5, resulting in a speed of about 200,000 km/s. The exact numbers depend on the material used.

But the usual optic fibers already work with the usual refractive index, I thought the main problems were dispersion and losses in the material. But maybe the evanescent waves are also significant as a loss mechanism (and slowing the light in the core definitely will reduce the range of the evanescent waves, it might perhaps simplify the outer layer which surrounds the core to contain them.)

@JosBergervoet I thought evanescent waves had an average intensity of zero since all the intensity is transmitted in total internal reflection, how can they be a source of energy loss?

Light is not like rays that completely stay inside the core. The true solution of the wave equation extends to the outside region (the cladding, and ultimately even a little bit into the air outside the cladding), but it is exponentially decaying with distance so the power moving outward is zero, although there will be losses in the material (but not necessarily more than for light that stays in the core...) https://cdn.gophotonics.com/community/9_638230999260081431.jpg

This is really engineering more than physics. Vast resources have been expended developing methods of purifying glass to make optical fibers with very low loss. This allows us to have fibers that lose less than 0.2 dB per kilometer of fiber.
But silica glass is silica glass. The refractive index is about 1.5, so the propagation velocity is about 0.67c. The only way to change this dramatically would be to find another material other than glass to make fiber out of, and to expend comparable resources to what have been expended in 50 years of glass fiber development to matching the loss performance of glass.
The difference in index between the core and cladding is quite small, less than 1%, and doesn't have a big effect on the propagation velocity in the axial direction.

can we optimize the value of $n'$ in order to lose as little information as possible while ensuring the speed of light in the fiber is high enough?

From a physics standpoint, there's no reason we couldn't use a core material with an index of 1.01 and vacuum as the cladding material and achieve the same index contrast as we have in glass with a 50% increase in propagation velocity. (But also, 50% increase in propagation velocity is the most that is possible to achieve)
But practically, we don't know how to make the side-walls of such a structure smooth enough not to cause losses, or how to make such a structure uniform in diameter and 100's of km long, or how to avoid damaging such a structure when deployed in a trench in the ground or in an undersea cable.
And given how well glass fibers work, there hasn't been any motivation to try to do so when the maximum possible improvement is 50% increase in propagation velocity.
In comments you said,

we want to ensure none of the light escapes, then the refractive index of the fiber should be very high, but this would make the signal go slower

We actually don't want to increase the index contrast too much, because we (looking at it from a ray optics point of view) really only want to allow beams to pass down the fiber very close to directly along the axis.
If we increased the index to allow highly off-axis beams to travel along the fiber, they would propagate more slowly than the on-axis beams, and any pulse of light we fed into the fiber would spread out as it travels as some of its power followed off-axis paths and some of its power followed on-axis paths. This would limit how quickly we could switch on and off the input light and still be able to distinguish the individual pulses at the far end of the fiber.
That means that even if this reduced the latency of the fiber (the time for light to travel from end to end) it would also reduce the bandwidth of the fiber (the amount of information that can be conveyed per unit time in a continuous stream).
